# Libtool outside autotools: how do I DESTDIR?

Tags: makefile, libtool

I'm using `libtool` (version 2.4.6) for creating a simple shared library
under GNU/Linux.

In my specific case, portability is not as important as simplicity: I don't
want to use the whole Autotools suite, nor CMake. I just want a simple
Makefile which can compile a shared library and install it properly.

I've got a couple of variables definitions, which follow the
[conventions of GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Variables.html)

```
prefix ?= /usr/local
exec_prefix ?= $(prefix)
libdir ?= $(exec_prefix)/lib
```

I want to support an `install` target, and I believe it should be roughly
like this:

```
LIBTOOL_LIB := libxyz.la

install: target = $(abspath $(DESTDIR))
install: all
    mkdir -p $(target)/$(libdir)
    libtool --mode=install install $(LIBTOOL_LIB) $(target)/$(libdir)
    libtool --mode=finish $(target)/$(libdir)
```

If I run `make install DESTDIR=./test` I get the following message:

```
mkdir -p /yadayada/src/test//usr/local/lib
libtool --mode=install install libtrullallero.la /yadayada/src/test//usr/local/lib
libtool: install: install .libs/libtrullallero.so.0.0.0 /yadayada/src.so.0.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /yadayada/src.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /yadayada/src.so; }; })
libtool: install: install .libs/libtrullallero.lai /yadayada/src.la
libtool: install: install .libs/libtrullallero.a /yadayada/src.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /yadayada/src.a
libtool: install: ranlib /yadayada/src.a
libtool: warning: remember to run 'libtool --finish /usr/local/lib'
libtool --mode=finish /yadayada/src/test//usr/local/lib
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /yadayada/src/test//usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /yadayada/src/test//usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I guess I deserve this notification, since I'm installing outside the
regular library path.  This is by the way the same message I would get in a
Autotools-based project, should I set a `--prefix` in some arbitrary path at
`./configure`.

There are however some weird things:

1. If I run `make install` as root (within a container, of course), without
   defining `DESTDIR`, I get the same kind of message.  This does not feel
   correct: this time I did not deserve it.
2. With or without `DESTDIR`, a call to `ldconfig` makes in my opinion no
   sense at this point.  And when I'm not running it as root, it should be
   also ineffective, yet the program succeeds.

Lurking in the libtool documentation, I've found a
[reference to the `-inst-prefix-dir` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Install-mode),
which should allow me to have a `DESTDIR`-like behaviour.

Perhaps this is what I do wrong.  However it behaves weirdly!

For starters, it seems to work only if specified at the end of the
`--mode=install` line.  In fact, if I do this:

```
install: target = $(abspath $(DESTDIR))
install: all
    mkdir -p $(target)/$(libdir)
    libtool --mode=install install -inst-prefix-dir $(target) $(LIBTOOL_LIB) $(target)/$(libdir)
    libtool --mode=finish $(target)/$(libdir)
```

…I clearly get a messy command line:

```
libtool: install: install -inst-prefix-dir /yadayada/libtrullallero/test/usr/local/lib/-inst-prefix-dir
install: invalid option -- 'i'
```

If I move `-inst-prefix-dir` to the end of the line, I just get another
wrong call to `install`:

```
mkdir -p /yadayada/src/libtrullallero/test//usr/local/lib
libtool --mode=install install libtrullallero.la /yadayada/src/libtrullallero/test
libtool: install: install .libs/libtrullallero.so.0.0.0 /yadayada/src/libtrullallero/test/libtrullallero.so.0.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /yadayada/src/libtrullallero/test && { ln -s -f libtrullallero.so.0.0.0 libtrullallero.so.0 || { rm -f libtrullallero.so.0 && ln -s libtrullallero.so.0.0.0 libtrullallero.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /yadayada/src/libtrullallero/test && { ln -s -f libtrullallero.so.0.0.0 libtrullallero.so || { rm -f libtrullallero.so && ln -s libtrullallero.so.0.0.0 libtrullallero.so; }; })
libtool: install: install .libs/libtrullallero.lai /yadayada/src/libtrullallero/test/libtrullallero.la
libtool: install: install /yadayada/src/libtrullallero/test/lib
install: omitting directory '/yadayada/src/libtrullallero/test//usr/local/lib'
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I must be doing something wrong, but I cannot spot it.  Any hint?

Comment: I've just run into a similar issue. It seems that _GNU Libtool_ documentation is wrong, and there is no `-inst-prefix-dir` option for `--mode=install`. Looking at the sources, it seems that there is an `-inst-prefix-dir` for `--mode=link`! If I can find out how it should be used, I'll post an answer.